# Balanced Payment integration for iOS

Tags: iphone, balanced-payments

I am trying to do the payment using https://www.balancedpayments.com/ . They have their iPhone library for this https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios . The problem is that there is not enough documentation on how the Balanced.framework has to be added in the XCode 4.5 project?

Answer (score 3):

1. [Download the Balanced framework](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios).
2. Add Balanced.framework to your project and to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.
3. Add CoreTelephony.framework to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.

Usage:

```
#import <Balanced/Balanced.h>
Balanced *balanced = [[Balanced alloc] initWithMarketplaceURI:@"/v1/marketplaces/TEST-MP2autgNHAZxRWZs76RriOze"];
BPCard *card = [[BPCard alloc] initWithNumber:@"4242424242424242" expirationMonth:8 expirationYear:2025 securityCode:@"123"];
```

If you need more help, look at the example project they have attached...

Comment: Please go through the site again...The option to download the balanced framework is not clickable...So the problem is how can the balanced framework be downloaded ?

Comment: I tried copying the framework but not able to. If it was some file I would have simply copied it. There should be some unique way of copying it as this is a static framework. Please let me know if you know about the process....

Comment: go to Build Phases under Settings tab -> Link Binary with Libraries -> click the + sign and in that, click the add other option. Use that to add the static framework...

Comment: Yes you are correct that is a normal way of adding framework..you get a list of frameworks and you select the one you want. But in this case there is no Balanced Framework in this list. Have you really integrated this library?

Comment: Check under Products in the example project, you can see the Balanced Framework.. Use that...

Answer (score 1):

You Just Need to add those Balanced- Classes as a static library, It will work out.

Add a Static Library to your Project.
Now add those balanced classes to your static Library.

Goto YourProject->Target->BuildPhases->LinkWithBinaryLibraries
Here add the StaticLibrary.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this [issue](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios/issues/1) on Github.  The lack of linking Balanced.framework is related to Xcode templates. The fix is documented in the project's ["Contributing"](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios#contributing) section. You need to build it.

Answer (score 1):

The balanced-ios project has changed quite a bit since this question was asked. It now creates a static library instead of a framework. This change was made for the reasons described in [balanced-ios Project Architecture.](http://remear.unfiniti.com/balanced-ios-project-architecture)

To integrate balanced-ios into iOS projects, do the following:

- Download the latest pre-built release zip from https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios/releases
- Copy balanced.a to your project
- Add balanced.a to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Add CoreTelephony.framework to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
- Copy includes/balanced to your project's include folder (or create an include folder and copy includes/balanced to it) includes is automatically included in header search paths. Drag includes to your project so you can see the files from there. If you copy the include files to a location other than includes you'll probably need to add the path to User Header Search Paths in your project settings

Code usage examples can be found in the README at https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ios